# Cross tabulate data of products sold broken down by revenue and by product sold

Tags: mysql, sql

Issues in getting the right frequency for the cross tabulated data. My expected output is something like this:

I tried replacing the COUNT statement with SUM statement

````
                 SUM(IF(product.product_id = 1, line_item.quantity, 0)) AS Soda,
                 SUM(IF(product.product_id = 2, line_item.quantity, 0)) AS Liquor,
                 SUM(IF(product.product_id = 3, line_item.quantity, 0)) AS Lemon,
                 SUM(IF(product.product_id = 4, line_item.quantity, 0)) AS Mango,
                 SUM(IF(product.product_id = 5, line_item.quantity, 0)) AS Inhaler,
                 SUM(1) AS Count

FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    0 lo,  500 hi UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000    UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500    UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000    UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON (product.price * line_item.quantity) BETWEEN ranges.lo AND ranges.hi
GROUP BY ranges.lo, ranges.hi```

It is getting closer because it is distributing already the values in its ranges just that the values are not correct. I am expecting to see something like this:

[Expected Result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuB92.png
````

Comment: `My code seem not to work` - any particular reason for not telling us exactly what does not work in your code? Do you get any error messages? Is the result different from what you expect? If so, what's different?

Comment: It is different from my expected result. I have embedded the imagehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/5s71f.png. Contrary to this I am getting only 9, 2, 5, 3, and 1 in all the columns or fields as the result of the code above. Any help will be of great significance.

Comment: Here's my entire tables: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9231b2684397cdce045ac396c68bc081

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my code here is the answer:

```
                 SUM(product.product_id = 1) AS Soda,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 2) AS Liquor,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 3) AS Lemon,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 4) AS Mango,
                 SUM(product.product_id = 5) AS Inhaler,
                 SUM(1) AS Count

FROM line_item
JOIN product USING (product_id)
JOIN ( SELECT    0 lo,  500 hi UNION
       SELECT  501   , 1000    UNION
       SELECT 1001   , 1500    UNION
       SELECT 1501   , 2000    UNION
       SELECT 2001   , 2500 ) ranges ON product.price * line_item.quantity BETWEEN ranges.lo AND ranges.hi
GROUP BY ranges.lo, ranges.hi
```

Comment: Edit your question and put this content there. Then delete this post because it is not an answer.

Comment: I think I have found a way sir forpas. Probably not the best answer but did work.